# Tesseract OCR Engine on ubuntu how to

Tags: ocr

I've installed `tesseract-ocr`. I was looking at the manual, but i can't see an option that i can define an image bounds (X,Y,W,H)

Can someone help about it , or am asking in a wrong place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line, you can run something like this:

`tesseract $imageFile $hocr hocr`  with version 3+ of tesseract.

`$imageFile` is the input, `$hocr` = HTML OCR file.

You can parse the file (e.g., with PHP) and get a box for each word.  This will help you get the coordinates of every word.

We use this method to make a custom search-able PDF ... We place the text on a page, then overlay the original image. This process can also be simplified with:  [`man hocr2pdf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/hocr2pdf.1.html)

---

We then use the classic and lightweight [R&OS PDF](http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/) to build the PDF on the fly with a custom script to rotate the image. I am attaching the updated function (with the updated "stream" function for "resume" support ... Accept-Ranges

```
class Mpdf extends Cezpdf 
{

function addPngFromFile($file,$x,$y,$w=0,$h=0,$angle=0)
{
  // read in a png file, interpret it, then add to the system
  $error=0;
  $tmp = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
  set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
  $fp = @fopen($file,'rb');
  if ($fp){
    $data='';
    while(!feof($fp)){
      $data .= fread($fp,1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
  } else {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg = 'trouble opening file: '.$file;
  }
  set_magic_quotes_runtime($tmp);

  if (!$error){
    $header = chr(137).chr(80).chr(78).chr(71).chr(13).chr(10).chr(26).chr(10);
    if (substr($data,0,8)!=$header){
      $error=1;
      $errormsg = 'this file does not have a valid header';
    }
  }

  if (!$error){
    // set pointer
    $p = 8;
    $len = strlen($data);
    // cycle through the file, identifying chunks
    $haveHeader=0;
    $info=array();
    $idata='';
    $pdata='';
    while ($p<$len){
      $chunkLen = $this->PRVT_getBytes($data,$p,4);
      $chunkType = substr($data,$p+4,4);

      switch($chunkType){
    case 'IHDR':
      // this is where all the file information comes from
      $info['width']=$this->PRVT_getBytes($data,$p+8,4);
      $info['height']=$this->PRVT_getBytes($data,$p+12,4);
      $info['bitDepth']=ord($data[$p+16]);
      $info['colorType']=ord($data[$p+17]);
      $info['compressionMethod']=ord($data[$p+18]);
      $info['filterMethod']=ord($data[$p+19]);
      $info['interlaceMethod']=ord($data[$p+20]);
      $haveHeader=1;
      if ($info['compressionMethod']!=0){
        $error=1;
        $errormsg = 'unsupported compression method';
      }
      if ($info['filterMethod']!=0){
        $error=1;
        $errormsg = 'unsupported filter method';
      }
      break;
    case 'PLTE':
      $pdata.=substr($data,$p+8,$chunkLen);
      break;
    case 'IDAT':
      $idata.=substr($data,$p+8,$chunkLen);
      break;
    case 'tRNS': 
      //this chunk can only occur once and it must occur after the PLTE chunk and before IDAT chunk 
      //print "tRNS found, color type = ".$info['colorType']."<BR>"; 
      $transparency = array();
      if ($info['colorType'] == 3) { // indexed color, rbg 
      /* corresponding to entries in the plte chunk 
      Alpha for palette index 0: 1 byte 
      Alpha for palette index 1: 1 byte 
      ...etc... 
      */ 
        // there will be one entry for each palette entry. up until the last non-opaque entry.
        // set up an array, stretching over all palette entries which will be o (opaque) or 1 (transparent)
        $transparency['type']='indexed';
        $numPalette = strlen($pdata)/3;
        $trans=0;
        for ($i=$chunkLen;$i>=0;$i--){
          if (ord($data[$p+8+$i])==0){
        $trans=$i;
          }
        }
        $transparency['data'] = $trans;

      } elseif($info['colorType'] == 0) { // grayscale 
      /* corresponding to entries in the plte chunk 
      Gray: 2 bytes, range 0 .. (2^bitdepth)-1 
      */ 
        $transparency['type']='indexed';
        $transparency['data'] = ord($data[$p+8+1]);

      } elseif($info['colorType'] == 2) { // truecolor 
      /* corresponding to entries in the plte chunk 
      Red: 2 bytes, range 0 .. (2^bitdepth)-1 
      Green: 2 bytes, range 0 .. (2^bitdepth)-1 
      Blue: 2 bytes, range 0 .. (2^bitdepth)-1 
      */ 
        $transparency['r']=$this->PRVT_getBytes($data,$p+8,2); // r from truecolor 
        $transparency['g']=$this->PRVT_getBytes($data,$p+10,2); // g from truecolor 
        $transparency['b']=$this->PRVT_getBytes($data,$p+12,2); // b from truecolor 

      } else { 
      //unsupported transparency type 
      } 
      // KS End new code 
      break; 
    default:
      break;
      }

      $p += $chunkLen+12;
    }

    if(!$haveHeader){
      $error = 1;
      $errormsg = 'information header is missing';
    }
    if (isset($info['interlaceMethod']) && $info['interlaceMethod']){
      $error = 1;
      $errormsg = 'There appears to be no support for interlaced images in pdf.';
    }
  }

  if (!$error && $info['bitDepth'] > 8){
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg = 'only bit depth of 8 or less is supported';
  }

  if (!$error){
    if ($info['colorType']!=2 && $info['colorType']!=0 && $info['colorType']!=3){
      $error = 1;
      $errormsg = 'transparancey alpha channel not supported, transparency only supported for palette images.';
    } else {
      switch ($info['colorType']){
    case 3:
      $color = 'DeviceRGB';
      $ncolor=1;
      break;
    case 2:
      $color = 'DeviceRGB';
      $ncolor=3;
      break;
    case 0:
      $color = 'DeviceGray';
      $ncolor=1;
      break;
      }
    }
  }
  if ($error){
    $this->addMessage('PNG error - ('.$file.') '.$errormsg);
    return;
  }
  if ($w==0){
    $w=$h/$info['height']*$info['width'];
  }
  if ($h==0){
    $h=$w*$info['height']/$info['width'];
  }

  // so this image is ok... add it in.
  $this->numImages++;
  $im=$this->numImages;
  $label='I'.$im;
  $this->numObj++;
  $options = array('label'=>$label,'data'=>$idata,'bitsPerComponent'=>$info['bitDepth'],'pdata'=>$pdata
                      ,'iw'=>$info['width'],'ih'=>$info['height'],'type'=>'png','color'=>$color,'ncolor'=>$ncolor);
  if (isset($transparency)){
    $options['transparency']=$transparency;
  }

  $this->o_image($this->numObj,'new',$options);

    # $angle in degrees
    $this->objects[$this->currentContents]['c'].="\nq";
    $this->objects[$this->currentContents]['c'].="\n".sprintf('%.3f',$w)." 0 0 ".sprintf('%.3f',$h)." ".sprintf('%.3f',$x)." ".sprintf('%.3f',$y)." cm";

            {
            $this->objects[$this->currentContents]['c'].="\n"."%%angle $angle ";

            $a = deg2rad((float)$angle);
                $this->objects[$this->currentContents]['c'].="\n".sprintf('%.6f',cos($a))." ".sprintf('%.6f',sin($a))." ".sprintf('%.6f',-1*sin($a))." ".sprintf('%.6f',cos($a))." 0 0 cm";
            }

    $this->objects[$this->currentContents]['c'].="\n/".$label.' Do';
    $this->objects[$this->currentContents]['c'].="\nQ";


}



function stream($options=''){
  // setting the options allows the adjustment of the headers
  // values at the moment are:
  // 'Content-Disposition'=>'filename'  - sets the filename, though not too sure how well this will 
  //        work as in my trial the browser seems to use the filename of the php file with .pdf on the end
  // 'Accept-Ranges'=>1 or 0 - if this is not set to 1, then this header is not included, off by default
  //    this header seems to have caused some problems despite tha fact that it is supposed to solve
  //    them, so I am leaving it off by default.
  // 'compress'=> 1 or 0 - apply content stream compression, this is on (1) by default
  if (!is_array($options)){
    $options=array();
  }
  if ( isset($options['compress']) && $options['compress']==0){
    $tmp = $this->output(1);
  } else {
    $tmp = $this->output();
  }
  header("Content-type: application/pdf");
  header("Content-Length: ".strlen(ltrim($tmp)));
  $fileName = (isset($options['Content-Disposition'])?$options['Content-Disposition']:'file.pdf');
  header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$fileName);
  if (isset($options['Accept-Ranges']) && $options['Accept-Ranges']==1){
    header("Accept-Ranges: ".strlen(ltrim($tmp))); 
  }
  echo ltrim($tmp);
}

}
```

Comment: +1. Somehow different but related question: If I have a pdf file and a html file in hocr format. Can I merge the hocr file into the pdf file, to make the pdf file searchable, without converting the pdf file to single-page image files? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170133/merge-and-export-ocred-text-into-and-from-a-pdf-file

Comment: The answer is yes.  Per the URL you mention Tim, there are tools that do this work for you.  In my work, I parse the hocr file, spell check it, get additional data from the TESSERACT function (e.g., the angle of rotation).  Then I take the hocr data, and create a cleaned, searchable PDF.  Rotated, common left column edge, white border, etc.  Compare [Google's OCR text and PDF](http://md5.mshaffer.com/download-calculator/Google-US6469.pdf) to [my OCR text and PDF](http://md5.mshaffer.com/download-calculator/Mergent-00006469.pdf)

Comment: how did you do it?

Comment: We first decided to tesseract a single page at a time (to prevent the "heuristic bayesian classifier" to do something weird).  Second we hacked tesseract to append angle of rotation within the text (API can do this maybe, we modified the .cpp header and recompiled a program called TESS).  Third, we parsed each page, and did our own page-layout analysis based on each words bbox (we didn't trust the TESS result of page-layout analysis).  We rotated each bbox based on the angle for the page... we calculated cols, and we aligned cols / top rows across pages to be normalized.

Comment: We then use the classic and lightweight [R&OS PDF](http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/) to build the PDF on the fly with a custom script to rotate the image.